# Can server communicate directly to client?

Tags: webserver, server, client, client-server, windows-server-2012

Everybody knows that client always request to server to execute script and get required data and we can give lot of examples of this.

But the question is that. Is there any example that server directly communicate/request to client. The server is not categorized i mean that any server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't get it clearly, can you explain a little bit what you actually want to know.

Comment: for example you want data from server you generate request and you get data. if requirement changed and server want some data from client then what to? understand.

Comment: Use websocket messages to request data from the client after it has opened a websocket connection with the server.